# Tkinter frame not appearing when using .place() but does when using .pack(), even with the same coordinates

Tags: python, class, tkinter, button, canvas

I created a scrollable frame with buttons that are place using the .pack() method. It worked well but now I want to change it to .place() in order to have more control on the button placement.

Problem: when I replaced .pack() by .place(), every widget were gone. Even after checking that the coordinates are still right and the dimensions of each widgets and frame should be too

The problem is a bit complex because I want to make multiples frames, corresponding to multiple objects of a class "Data_widget", to appear in a scrollable area of a parent class "Plot_window". This is for a data visualisation project.

Here is the parent class initialization with the declaration of each areas:

```
class PlotWindow(tk.Frame):
    """ This Class creates the main window with the curve plot and general buttons like open files, Clear all, Plot all.
    
    Arguments:
    -master: a parent window, not necessary
    -existing_data_widgets_list: used by the button "plot multiple selection"
        to create a new instance of PlotWindow with already selected data
    -existing_filepath_list: the corresponding list of filepath for the existing_data_widgets_list

    Methods:
    -create_general_controls : creates general controls like Open file, clear all, plot all...
    -matplotlib_spec : defines default matplotlib specifications
    -display_error : displays a message of error, used by other methods  (example: "no data loaded" or "no selection")
                    can also be used for informative messages (example: "plot cleared")
    -load_folder : allows to select multiple folders and detects all CSV file in them
    -load_CSVfile : allows to select multiple CSV files
    -plot_widget : called by each widget method master_plot to plot widget curve with selected widget variables
    -clear_widget_plots : called by each widget method master_clear_plot to clear the widget plot(s)
    -clear_all_plot : clear all plots
    -add_selection : allows to select a range of data from multiple curves with rectangle selector
                            can be called again to add selection to already selected data
    -cancel_selection : empty the selection of the add_selection method
    -plot_add_selection : plot the selection of the add_selection method in another PlotWindow instance
                                creates a widget in this new instance for each widget that have been selected in previous PlotWindow
    -create_createvar_popup : create popup that allows to the create a new variable as function of existing variables
    -linear_regression_selection : make a linear regression of rectangle selection. plot the line on the rectangle selection
    """
    def __init__(self, master=None, existing_data_widgets_list=[], existing_filepath_list=[], widgets_x_var=None, widgets_y_var=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        root.title("its plotin time")
        self.master = master
        self.pack()

        self.widgets_list = []                                      #stores all instances of Data_Widget class created
        self.lines = []                                             #stores the plt.plot objects (the curves) to be able to hide/show them
        self.lines_ids = []                                         #stores a number for each plot (each plot_id = widget_id it is plotted from)
        ...
        self.create_general_controls()                              #create all buttons and graphic elements

    def create_general_controls(self):       #create the general widgets

        # Create menu
        menubar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        ...

        # Create figure
        self.color_cycle=['blue', 'coral', 'lime', 'lavender', 'turquoise', 'darkgreen', 'tan', 'salmon']
        self.figure_frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        ...
        
        # Create general controls
        self.general_controls_frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.general_controls_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=None, expand=False)

        self.error_label = tk.Label(self.general_controls_frame, text="")
        self.error_label.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        ...

                # Create the widgets area
        # Create the main frame for the scrollable area
        self.widgets_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, highlightthickness=3, highlightbackground="orange")
        self.widgets_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Create the canvas
        self.widgets_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.widgets_frame, width=550, highlightbackground="purple")
        self.widgets_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Create the scrollbar and attach it to the canvas
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.widgets_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.widgets_canvas.yview)
        self.widgets_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        # Create the window that the canvas will use as the scrollable area
        self.scrollable_widgets_frame = tk.Frame(self.widgets_canvas, highlightbackground="green")
        # self.scrollable_widgets_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.scrollable_widgets_frame.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relwidth=1, relheight=1, anchor="nw")
        self.widgets_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_widgets_frame, anchor="nw")

        # Raise the scrollable_widgets_frame to the top of the stacking order
        self.scrollable_widgets_frame.lift()
```

Here is the Data_widget child class:

```
class Data_Widget():
    """ This Class creates the main window with the curve plot and general buttons like open files, Clear all, Plot all.
    
    Arguments:
    -master: the parent window, automatically the PlotWindow class
    -data: data loaded into the widget self.data used to plot the curve
    -filepath: the filepath of the loaded data
    -color: color of the curve
    
    methods:
    -create_widget_controls : create the controls (buttons...)
    -set_widget_color : set the color of the associated curve
    -set_x_var and set_y_var : set the x and y var of the plotted curve
    -master_plot : gives the order of plotting the curve to the master class (PlotWindow) (method plot_widget)
    -master_clear_plot : gives the order of clearing the plot to the master class (PlotWindow) (method clear_widget_plots)
    -delete_widget : delete the widget
    -create_exportload_popup : export the data contained in the widget as CSV file.
                Used where widget has been created by selecting data from another widget with PlotWindow multiple selection method
    """
    def __init__(self, master, data = pd.DataFrame(), filepath='Nothing loaded', x_var=None, y_var= None, color="blue"):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        # Create variables for data and plot
        self.widget_id=0                            #id of the widget   
        self.filepath=filepath                      #filepath of the loaded data
        self.data = data                            #dataframe loaded into the widget
        self.selected_data = pd.DataFrame()         #data selected by the user
        self.x_var = x_var                          #x variable of the plotted curve
        self.y_var = y_var                          #y variable of the plotted curve
        self.color = color                          #color of the plotted curve
        self.create_widget_controls()               #create the controls (buttons...)
        self.peaks_indices = []                     #list of the indices of the peaks of the loaded curve

    def __del__(self):
        print ("Obsolete widget number " + str(self.widget_id) + " got destroyed, it will come back to haunt you")

    def create_widget_controls(self):
        # Create and place the frame with the specified coordinates and dimensions
        self.widget_frame = tk.Frame(self.master.scrollable_widgets_frame, bg="yellow")
        self.widget_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=None, expand=False)
        # Raise the widget_frame to the top of the stacking order
        self.widget_frame.lift()

        # Create and place the widgets within the frame with updated coordinates and dimensions
        self.filename_label = tk.Label(self.widget_frame, text="-------------- " + os.path.basename(self.filepath) + " --------------")
        self.filename_label.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, anchor="nw")

        self.x_label = tk.Label(self.widget_frame, text="X axis variable")
        self.x_label.place(x=10, y=20, width=80)

        self.x_var_dropdown_label = tk.StringVar()
        self.x_var_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.widget_frame, self.x_var_dropdown_label, "")
        self.x_var_dropdown.place(x=10, y=40, width=80)
        ...
```

You can see I added color to the area elements and I think the problem might be situated around the line         `self.scrollable_widgets_frame = tk.Frame(self.widgets_canvas, highlightbackground="green")` because I can't see any green even though I can see the purple canvas.

I tried to "lift" the scrollable_widget_frame on top of the others but it changed nothing.

Here is a code you can copy paste to see what I want to see and that is not appearing:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

# Create the main tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a frame to hold the widgets
widget_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="yellow")
widget_frame.place(x=0, y=0, width=400, height=150)

# Create and place the widgets within the frame
filename_label = tk.Label(widget_frame, text="-------------- your_filepath_here --------------")
filename_label.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, anchor="nw")

x_label = tk.Label(widget_frame, text="X axis variable")
x_label.place(x=10, y=20, width=80)

x_var_dropdown_label = tk.StringVar()
x_var_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(widget_frame, x_var_dropdown_label, "")
x_var_dropdown.place(x=10, y=40, width=80)

y_label = tk.Label(widget_frame, text="Y axis variable")
y_label.place(x=10, y=70, width=80)

y_var_dropdown_label = tk.StringVar()
y_var_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(widget_frame, y_var_dropdown_label, "")
y_var_dropdown.place(x=10, y=90, width=80)

plot_button = tk.Button(widget_frame, text="Plot", command=None)  # Replace 'None' with the appropriate function
plot_button.place(x=100, y=30, width=50, height=40)

clear_button = tk.Button(widget_frame, text="Clear", command=None)  # Replace 'None' with the appropriate function
clear_button.place(x=100, y=80, width=50, height=40)

detect_peaks_button = tk.Button(widget_frame, text="Detect\npeaks", command=None)  # Replace 'None' with the appropriate function
detect_peaks_button.place(x=160, y=30, width=50, height=40)

todo_button = tk.Button(widget_frame, text="✍(◔◡◔)", command=None)  # Replace 'None' with the appropriate function
todo_button.place(x=160, y=80, width=50, height=40)

color_button = tk.Button(widget_frame, text="color", bg="blue", fg="white", command=None)  # Replace 'your_color_here' and 'None' with the appropriate color and function
color_button.place(x=220, y=30, width=50, height=40)

exportload_button = tk.Button(widget_frame, text="Export\n as csv", command=None)  # Replace 'None' with the appropriate function
exportload_button.place(x=220, y=80, width=50, height=40)

delete_button = tk.Button(widget_frame, text="X", command=None)  # Replace 'None' with the appropriate function
# delete_button.place(anchor="ne", x=400, y=30, width=15, height=15)
delete_button.place(relx=1.0, rely=0.0, anchor="ne")

# Start the tkinter main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to pare this down to a [mre] - this is likely way more code than we need

Comment: Note that `self.widget_frame` will be zero size initially because widgets (its children) using `.place()` will not adjust parent size automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also thought of the `self.widget_frame` being zero size and not updating but I don't see how this could be possible since it's coded to be the same size than its master `widgets_canvas` using the `relwidth=1, relheight=1` parameters. And I can see the purple `widgets_canvas` taking all the space.

Comment: (Also, I'm new to Stack, why are your comments being flagged? They seem pretty reasonable to me)

Comment: The comments are not being flagged.  The gray flag is an icon that allows YOU to flag offensive comments.

Comment: Note that `self.scrollable_widgets_frame.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relwidth=1, relheight=1, anchor="nw")` will be override by `self.widgets_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_widgets_frame, anchor="nw")`.  Try specifying the `width` and `height` options when creating `self.widget_frame`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you acw1668. I did that but it changed nothing. Also I already know that `widgets_frame` and `widgets_canvas`display correctly thanks to their color. But I still can't figure out why `scrollable_widgets_frame` doesn't show up.